# MSSQL 2014 and Dynamics CRM 2013 SP1 (springwave)

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-dynamics-crm

Microsoft says MSSQL 2014 is not supported with MS Dynamics CRM 2013 (SP1 springwave '14).

Is this because there are known problems with that configuration? Or does it just mean that Microsoft did not test that configuration?

Does any of you have experience running this combination (maybe in compatibility mode?) Which problems have you run into and how big were they?

Answer (score 0):

**When trying to install CRM 2013 with SQL 2014 instance:**

SQL Server edition

Cause

Setup found an installed edition of Microsoft SQL Server that is not supported by this version of Microsoft Dynamics CRM.

Solution

Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 supports most versions of the following Microsoft SQL Server editions. At least one Microsoft SQL Server instance is required and must be installed on a Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2012 64-bit version, running, and available for Microsoft Dynamics CRM:

Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Microsoft SQL Server 2012